# method selection in apache cxf with queryParam

Tags: java, rest, path, cxf

I created a java rest resource with 2 methods both listening on the same path, but one with `@QueryParam` annotation as method parameter

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    public Response filter(){  
        System.out.println("init");
        return Response.accepted("Hello world").build();
    }

    @GET    
    public Response filterQuery(@QueryParam("filter") String filterQuery) {
        return Response.accepted("filter: " + filterQuery).build();
        //... parsing filter
    } 
}
```

But when I try `GET` on `../test?filter=name:Juraj;location:Slovakia` or on `../test` it is always calling the `filter()` method

Is it not enough to define the QueryParam to get the second method be called? I would like to offer the user to parametrize on the same url, **not** on the `/test/filter?name=...`

Can I do this somehow?
Using `apache-cxf 3.0.0-milestone2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a `@QueryParam` does not mean that this parameter is required. If the query-string is empty or not including the defined query-param the value of the parameter will be `null`.

So both methods are ambiguous and seems like the first one wins. If you want two methods you can easily check for `null` and call the other method.

```
@GET    
public Response filterQuery(@QueryParam("filter") String filterQuery) {
    if (filterQuery == null) {
        return filter();
    }
    return Response.accepted("filter: " + filterQuery).build();
} 

private Response filter() {  
    return Response.accepted("Hello world").build();
}
```