# CXF doesn't match the right target method depending of QueryParam arguments

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, cxf

I'm writing a RESTful Web-Service but CXF doesn't match the **right target method** when the ***URI paths* are identical** but only `@QueryParam` parameters are different...

I know that `@QueryParam` parameters are optional and as it's said [in the answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625927/method-selection-in-apache-cxf-with-queryparam): "*both methods are ambiguous* [at *URI paths* level] *and seems like the first one wins*"...

ex: `http://mydomain/property?key=sthA` or `http://mydomain/property?value=sthB`, CXF will match the same method unfortunately.

```
@Path("/property")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface PropertyService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    AppSetting findPropertyById(@PathParam("id") String id); /* /property/123 */

    @GET
    Property findPropertyByKey(@QueryParam("key") String key); /* /property?key=sth */

    @GET
    List<Property> getPropertiesByValue(@QueryParam("value") String value); /* /property?value=sth */

}
```

So, what is the best solution between:

- having one method that will handle any possible `@QueryParam` parameters for a specific *URI path* (here "*/property?[key=sthA][&value=sthB][...]*")
- or set some RegExp directly in the value of the `@Path` annotation to "help" CXF to match *URI path* with the right method (here: "*/property?key=sthA*" should match the method with "`@Path({key:.*})`" annotation)
- or any other possible solution

?

Thks

Comment: maybe urls like /property/id/{id} and /property/key/{key} would be better in this case.

Comment: It's a solution but that doesn't fit to the concept where an _URI path_ correspond to a resource and `@QueryParam` are only used for filtering result list...

Comment: in that case if your regex solution works, i ll pick that

Comment: good to know :-) Currently I've chosen the first solution (a method by each _URI path_) for the PoC.